# gxp_googlegeocoder add to default geoexplorer viewer

Tags: javascript, boundless-suite, geoexplorer, geocoding

I have an opengeo 4.1 running on my webserver (windows). I use the default geoexplorer viewer to share my maps and I am very happy with all the default functions, however I would like to add  the geocoder function as well.  I don't want to build an own custom viewer, because I don't have that knowledge, but I would like to add the geocoder to the default geoexplorer viewer. Is anybody can provide me a solution?

Comment: I would like to add this: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/gxp/viewer/geocoder.html
To my default geoexplorer/composer (myip:port/geoexplorer/composer/). I can edit the composer.html but I don't know how can I add the geocoder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read this: http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/webapps/gxp/viewer/geocoder.html and apply it to the tools array somewhere here in GeoExplorer: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js#L58

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my opengeo folder I only have one composer.js but that one looks completely different from you one in the link. I have just this one: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/root/composer.js

Comment: Nothing happens when I edit that file.
http://91.109.10.182:8080/geoexplorer/composer/
That is my default composer, I would like to add to here the geocoder function.
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\webapps\geoexplorer\WEB-INF\app\templates\composer.html When I edit this file and save it I can see the changes straight away in the browser.. Should I add the extra bits here?

Comment: And sorry maybe it's important but I have version 3.1 not 4.1

Comment: Could I get a bit more help please? Can I do it without creating custom map app?